# Writing to standard user's HKCU Registry value via administrator account

Tags: registry, wallpaper, regedit, registrykey, gpo

GPO sets HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\ActiveDesktop\NoChangingWallPaper to 1, thus locking me to an ugly corporate wallpaper.

The key's permissions belong to the Administrators' group. In Regedit I cannot modify or delete the key as my standard user account.

I have a local admin account I can access, which would have permission to change this value. How can I edit the current standard user's reg key using my local admin access without having to switch profiles (if I log out and log back in, it'll pull the GPO again reverting the key value.

Ideally I'd like to write a BAT or PowerShell script to change this key each time I log in.

Thanks

Edit: Of course, minutes after I ask this, I figured it out. What I did (in case anyone finds this):

Run RegEdit as Administrator, then I found the appropriate HKEY_USERS folder for my standard user, and set the key to 0.

Close RegEdit, open Task Manager, and end the 'Explorer.exe' process.

Open the Run dialogue and restart explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, minutes after I ask this, I figured it out. What I did (in case anyone finds this):

Run RegEdit as Administrator, then I found the appropriate HKEY_USERS folder for my standard user, and set the key to 0.

Close RegEdit, open Task Manager, and end the 'Explorer.exe' process.

Open the Run dialogue and restart explorer.

This will have to be done each time I log in to overwrite the GPO.